# Rails Server Callback to different domain

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, controller

I want to do the following: The client (from a different domain, right now a JQuery-Script on my local computer) sends a Ajax-Post to the server, the server saves the result to the server and sends HTML/text back to the client who injects it into his HTML.

This is the Ajax-Call:

```
  var params = '{"comment": "Test", "creator": "Prof Frick", "name":     "Rainer", "url": "' + url + '"}';
  alert(params);
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    data: params,
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/pages/postjson/',
    success: function(data) {
      $('h1').html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

This is my route:

```
match '/pages/postjson/' => 'pages#postjson'
```

And this is the controller:

```
  def postjson
    parsed_json = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(request.body.read) #
    @page = Page.where(:url => parsed_json["url"])
    new_obj = Page.new
    new_obj.name = parsed_json["name"]
    new_obj.creator = parsed_json["creator"]
    new_obj.url = parsed_json["url"]
    new_obj.comment = parsed_json["comment"]
    new_obj.save    
    render :json => @page[:name]
  end
```

I think my mistake is be quite basic and I really appreciate your help. My guess is that the mistake is either in

```
    @page = Page.where(:url => parsed_json["url"])
```

or in

```
    render :json => @page[:name]
```

because everything goes through, the json-data gets saved, the browser even alerts "Success", but the  I want to post to just disappears.

Thanks for your advice. General coding tips also always appreciated!

Comment: what did you get in ajax success callback?

Comment: with `datatype: "json",` in the JQuery-Code I get Null returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the puzzle (for me):

After reading a lot I found [this tutorial](http://davidsulc.com/blog/2011/04/10/implementing-a-public-api-in-rails-3/)

I changed my controller to look similar to this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js  { render :json => @page, :callback => params[:callback] }
```

And my JQuery-Function looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    processData: false,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/pages/postjson.js?callback=?',
    success: function(data) {
      $('h1').html(data.name);
      alert("Name: "+ data['name']);
    }
  });
});
```

So happy that it is finally working :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `render :json => something` you will get a json object as response. What you need in this case is a `render :js` and a view that is called `postjson.js.erb` (assuming you're using ERB). In that view, you have to write the necessary JavaScript code to manipulate you HTML the way you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am getting the request from and sending the data to another domain (like an API). Therefore, I don't use views.

Comment: Your hint with JS pointed me in the right direction. But the working solution (see below) looks quite different. I still render json, but format it as js. And the ajax-call had the wrong parameters. Still thanks though.